# Invoke component function from Chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security

Apologies if this is a dumb question, but I was wondering if it is at all possible to access a function defined in a React component from the browser? For example:

```
class Test extends React.Component {

  someFn = () => {
    console.log('hey!') 
  }

  render() { return <div>...</div> }
}
```

So once the website has loaded and the component has been mounted, is it possible to somehow access the javascript and invoke someFn()? I know that, for example, Redux variables exist on the global scope and those can be manipulated, but I'm unsure of class functions. If so, I would assume state objects on these classes to be editable as well, right?

Answer (score 3):

With [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi), you can select your component in the tree on the ⚛️Components dev tools tab.  Once selected, that component instance can be accessed in the console as `$r`, allowing you to invoke your function with `$r.someFn()`.

Comment: How can we do that for "FUNCTIONAL COMPONENTS" ?